# How to debug Mono itself?

Tags: debugging, mono, gdb, monodevelop

I want to fix [a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2907) in [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)'s XML deserializer.
The code is quite complex.

How can I run Mono itself in debug mode? (breakpoints, step-by-step, variables inspection).

Preferably in a graphical way.
If [Monodevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) can be used to debug Mono itself, that would be great.
I am on Linux Ubuntu 2012.04 and [have enabled debugging information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41610/how-do-i-rebuild-a-package-to-include-debugging-information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MonoDevelop, after loading the solution, go to the Edit menu -> Preferences. Select Debugger and uncheck "Debug project code only...".

Comment: lupus: that shows IL for me, not source code (even having installed the package "mono-dbg"). Am I missing something?

Comment: Most likely the source paths in the symbol files don't match the source location on your system. If you're debugging Mono, you should build Mono from source and target that runtime from MonoDevelop.